# How to make and exception using "if" in a wordpress php page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, statements

I am using a wordpress theme that has a specific layout feature for the blog template anytime "category" is used.

The blog template displays the date in a ribbon graphic and there is additional control to turn it on or off through an additional "epanel"  in wordpress.

I have 2 categories (Blog and Services). I would like to remove the DATE feature from being display only in the "Services" category.

It is added like this :

```
<?php if ( get_option('sky_postinfo1') ) { ?>
                <div class="post-date">
```

`sky_postinfo2` would mean that is off.

Each page has an H1 that echos the page title like this:

```
<h1 id="page-title"><?php echo esc_html( $et_page_title ); ?></h1>
```

Is there a way to write an exception to remove this only for the "Services" page?

Something like :

```
<?php 

 if { 
 ( $et_page_title = ('Services') get_option('sky_postinfo1');
 } else get_option('sky_postinfo2');

 ?>
```

I am sure I absolutely butchered the last part, but I am looking for direction if possible. Any help greatly appreciated. Is doing it this way practical or am I way of base?

Answer (score 0):

mhhhh, assuming the $et_page_title variable has this value on this page...

```
<?php if ( get_option('sky_postinfo1') && $et_page_title != 'Services') { ?>
                <div class="post-date">
```